# Javascript RegExp and \\

Tags: javascript, regex

I have the following expression: `^(0|1)\\1{1,}$`.

Why it works only when I use it with `new RegExp()`?

```
// return always false
/^(0|1)\\1{1,}$/.test("000"); 

// it works!
var pattern = new RegExp("^(0|1)\\1{1,}$"); 
pattern.test("000");
```

Comment: You just need to use `^(0|1)\1{1,}$` see here http://regex101.com/r/aT7lS2

Comment: As a side note, `/^([01])\1+$/` looks better.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Remove the second backslash:

```
/^(0|1)\1{1,}$/.test("000"); // true
```

The reason why that works is that backslashes are treated literally in regex literals, while they are escaped in strings (which is then escaped *again* in the regular expression).

For example:

```
new RegExp('\\\\').test('\\'); // true
/\\\\/.test('\\'); // false
new RegExp('\\\\').source; // '\\' - one backslash
/\\\\/.source; // '\\\\' - two backslashes

console.log('\\'); // shows one backslash
```

Answer (score 1):

When you use `RegExp`, the regular expression will be treated as string. So, you have to escape the `\` with `\\`. That escaping is not needed when you use it with `/.../` form. So, simply remove the second `\` in `\\`.

```
console.log(/^(0|1)\1{1,}$/.test("000"));
```

**Output**

```
true
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this regex by stripping `\\1` to `\1`:

```
/^(0|1)\1+$/.test("000");
```

When you construct `RegExp` object using a String you need double escaping:

1. 1st by String object
2. 2nd by Regex Engine

which is not needed here since you're directly constructing a regex using `/ and /`